# How to pass Multivalue parameters from main report to subreport in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I got a main report in Crystal using several formulas.
As I need to make a cross-chart with those formulas, I'm experiencing an issue due the fact formula cannot be used in chart/xtable since it is a print time formula.

I've understood there's a kind a workaround, and basically it consist to send the value as a string into a subreport. Once the values are in the subreport, is possible to create another formula to split the values.

I don't have any clue how to do that: so far I've created a subreport, used the "Change Sub Report" feature, created additional formula:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
stringvar array x;
numbervar i;
i := i + 1;
redim preserve x[i];
x[i] := ToText ({?Pm-@FLEET});
""
```

Tryed also some kind of serialization:

```
join(MakeArray (ToText ({?Pm-@afterDAY_X_CODE})), ',')
```

But what I obtain is just the last value.
Any idea on how to pass from Main report a multivalue paramentert and re-aggreagate in a cross chart into subreport?
Many Thanks

S.

Comment: have you tried using shared variables?

Comment: If I try to do that I encounter the same issue: "a print time formula that modifies variables is used in a char or map".